# ORACLE SET ROLE with EF Core

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, roles

Using Oracle, we have a very important Oracle connection security tool that is

SET ROLE *role* IDENTIFIED BY *password*

Note that it is not the Add Role of navigation used in Identity, but the ROLE of the ORACLE connection.

I'm having a hard time finding how to use this command with EntityFrameworkCore.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Or at least how to get the Oracle connection so that I can run the command explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try .FromSql like this.

[Executing Raw SQL Queries](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql)

Answer (score 1):

> Or at least how to get the Oracle connection so that I can run the command explicitly.

You can "drop down" to ADO.NET whenever you want, like this:

```
var con = db.Database.GetDbConnection();
con.Open();
var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SET ROLE role IDENTIFIED BY password";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

After `con.Open()` the connection will remain open for the lifetime of the DbContext.  You may need to un-set the role before disposing the DbContext and returning the connection to the connection pool.